# How to remove multiple root tags in XML using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

My XML looks like:

```
<PAYUSW2R>  
<G_EMPLOYEE1>
    ..
    .
</G_EMPLOYEE1>

</PAYUSW2R>
<PAYUSW2R>

<G_EMPLOYEE2>
    ..
    .
</G_EMPLOYEE2>

</PAYUSW2R>
```

I want to make this as a well formed XML as follows:

```
<PAYUSW2R>  
<G_EMPLOYEE1>
    ..
    .
</G_EMPLOYEE1>
<G_EMPLOYEE2>
    ..
    .
</G_EMPLOYEE2>  
</PAYUSW2R>
```

Basically I want to remove the extra root tags < PAYUSW2R >.
Can we achieve this using XSLT? Please provide some help here.

Comment: XSLT only works on valid XML. So you would have to give your original XML a root before you can use XSLT to fix the originally bad XML. That kind of defeats the point right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since XML input to XSLT needs to be well-formed, you'll have to initially wrap your instance in a temporary root element. How you do this will depend on how you're running your XSLT. It could be as simple as concatenating the new start/end tags with your existing XML.

What you should end up with is something like this:

```
<temp>
    <PAYUSW2R>  
        <G_EMPLOYEE1>
            ..
            .
        </G_EMPLOYEE1>

    </PAYUSW2R>
    <PAYUSW2R>

        <G_EMPLOYEE2>
            ..
            .
        </G_EMPLOYEE2>

    </PAYUSW2R>    
</temp>
```

Then your XSLT could look something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[1]"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*/*[1]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*|node()|following-sibling::*/*"/>
        </xsl:copy>        
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This would result in the output:

```
<PAYUSW2R>
   <G_EMPLOYEE1>
            ..
            .
        </G_EMPLOYEE1>
   <G_EMPLOYEE2>
            ..
            .
        </G_EMPLOYEE2>
</PAYUSW2R>
```

Comment: Hi Daniel,

Thanks for your reply. Your solution almost worked for me. But I have another issue in my XML.
My orginal XML looks like:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!-- Generated by Oracle Reports version 6.0.8.28.0 -->
<PAYUSW2R>  
<G_EMPLOYEE1>
    ..
    .
</G_EMPLOYEE1>

</PAYUSW2R>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!-- Generated by Oracle Reports version 6.0.8.28.0 -->
<PAYUSW2R>

<G_EMPLOYEE2>
    ..
    .
</G_EMPLOYEE2>

</PAYUSW2R>

Comment: So along with the root tag, the XML version line also getting repeated. The number of repetitions depends on the number of threads I am running.
This is making my XML non well formed. Your solution worked for me when I remove the XML version lines manually from the input XML.

Is there any way to remove these lines form the XML using XSLT?

Comment: @user3783052 - No, there's no way to do that with XSLT without doing additional pre-processing. What you could do is replace `<?xml` with something like `<?xml-delete-me` and add a template to your XSLT  that strips them: `<xsl:template match="processing-instruction()[name()='xml-delete-me']"/>`